# Not fetching the image from public folder( https://localhost/storage) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a web app. when i am uploading an image its not able to fetch from the public folder and giving me back a 404 error.When i checked the error its not able to access the http://localhost/storage and through me an error. I have attached the error screenshot please check and help me. 
Check out the codes.
Profile Model:

```
class Profile extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
public function image()
{
    if($this->media->first())
    {


        return $this->media->first()->getFullUrl('thumb');


    }


    return null;
}

    public function registerMediaConversions(?Media $media = null)
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
        ->width(100)
        ->height(100);
    }
}
```

ProfileController

```
public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $profile->clearMediaCollection('images');

        $profile->addMediaFromRequest('image')
                 ->toMediaCollection('images');

    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Show.blade.php

```
@method('PATCH')
                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                            <div class='profile-avatar'>
                                <div onclick="document.getElementById('image').click()" class="profile-avatar-overlay">
                                    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 32 32">

                                        <path d="M18 22.082v-1.649c2.203-1.241 4-4.337 4-7.432 0-4.971 0-9-6-9s-6 4.029-6 9c0 3.096 1.797 6.191 4 7.432v1.649c-6.784 0.555-12 3.888-12 7.918h28c0-4.030-5.216-7.364-12-7.918z"></path>
                                        </svg>

                                </div>
                                <img src="{{ $profile->image() }}" alt="" >

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

error image:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the URL that you saved in the database. Seems like you didn't save the URL correctly, as the error in console says. Also, where did you store the image, into the storage?

Comment: No i did'nt save any url to my database but the image is also uploaded to database and it saved in storage/app/public also.

Comment: the error depicting the "Not Found" image has no path, merely a filename that therefore suggests it is looking within the same folder that the current script is running in.

Comment: but clicking the error its giving a link http://localhost/storage/1/conversions/canon-thumb.jpg

Comment: when i visit the link it shows me Object Not Found

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan storage:link
```

That creates a symlink from public/storage to storage/app/public for you and that's all there is to it. Now any file in /storage/app/public can be accessed via a link like:

```
http://somedomain.com/storage/image.jpg
```

set your image src path like this:

```
{{ URL::to('image/' .$profile->image()) }}
```

Comment: now its shoing the image link like http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/http://localhost/storage/1/conversions/canon-thumb.jpg